# Parsing a config file with nested braces

Tags: perl, parsing

I put this script together to get what is inside the member's brackets.

This is not JSON - is it just a bracketed config file. I am trying to think of a better way to do it.

This shop is very limited on the modules that they use, which is kind of why I had to use
the on-off tags. If this could really done by a module, then I suppose I could get a requisition
to add a new module.

Be that as it may, is there a way to just get what is inside the member `{ ... }` like using a while loop instead of tagging each bracket with an on or off tag.

```
#!/sbcimp/dyn/data/EVT/GSD/scripts/perl/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %penny_hash = ();

my $penny_file = "penny_config.cfg";

open(FOOO, "<$penny_file") or die "Can't open $penny_file for reading: $!";

foreach my $line (<FOOO>) {
   chomp($line);

   if ($line =~ /^\s*TickSize\s+=\s+\{/) {
      $ticksize_flag = 1;
   }
   elsif (($ticksize_flag == 1) && ($line =~ /^\s*penny.*\s+=\s+\{/)) {
      $penny_flag = 1;
   }
   elsif (($penny_flag == 1) && ($line =~ /^\s*members\s+=\s+\{/)) {
      $member_flag = 1;
   }
   elsif (($member_flag == 1) && ($line =~ /\}/)) {
      $member_flag = 0;
   }
   elsif (($member_flag == 1) && ($line =~ /\s*(\S+)\s*$/)) {
      print $line ;
      print "\n";
   }
}
```

This is the config file

```
# Tick Size
# tr -d \  | sort -u
TickSizePostOpen = 1.00
TickSize = {
  penny1 = {
    TickSize = 0.00
    members = {
      IWM
      QQQ
      SPY
      SPY_TEST
    }
  }
  penny = {
    TickSize = </0.000/0.00/0.00
    members = {
A
AA
AAL
AAPL
ABT
ABT_SPIN
ZNGA
    }
  }
  notpenny = {
    TickSize = </9/9.99/9.99
  }
}
BIPP.QuoterOx = {
  Cup1and2 = {
    BIPP.QuoterOx = BIPP-ox-1
    members = {
      Cup_1
      Cup_2
    }
  }
TRAP.PxByGroup = 1
TRAP.Px = {
  group1 = {
    TRAP.Px = OPTxxxxxx
    members = {
      px.TRAP.1
    }
  }
  group2 = {
    TRAP.Px = OPTxxxxxx
    members = {
      px.TRAP.2
    }
  }
TRAP.QuoterOx = {
  Cup0 = {
    TRAP.QuoterOx = QESxxxxx
    members = {
      Cup_0
      Cup_99
    }
  }
  Cup1and4and10 = {
    TRAP.QuoterOx = ise-ox-1-4-10-dti
    members = {
      Cup_1
      Cup_4
      Cup_10
    }
  }
Cup56 = {
    TRAP.AuctionOx = ise-ox-56-ecl
    members = {
      Cup_56
    }
  }
}
TRAP.RotateQuote = {
  rotatenames = {
    TRAP.RotateQuote = 1
      members = {
              AAPL
              ADY
              AEIS
              AFAM
              AGP
              ALNY
              ZINC
      }
  }
}
Underlying = {
  Cup0 = {
    Underlying = MHR
    members = {
      Cup_0
    }
  }
  g1 = {
    Underlying = CEL
    members = {
      Cup_1
    }
  }
}
BIPP.Px = {
    group1 = {
        BIPP.Px = BOXPXMHR1
        members = {
            px.BIPP.1
        }
    }
    group2 = {
        BIPP.Px = BOXPXMHR2
        members = {
            px.BIPP.2
        }
    }
}
TWIG.Px = {
   AB = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR1
   members = {
     A
     B
   }
 }
   CD = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR2
   members = {
     C
     D
   }
 }
   NOPQR = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR6
   members = {
     N
     O
     P
     Q
     R
   }
 }
   STUV = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR7
       members = {
          S
          T
          U
          V
       }
   }
   WXYZ = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR8
       members = {
           W
           X
           Y
           Z
       }
   }
}
```

There are the results that I get:

```
      IWM
      QQQ
      SPY
      SPY_TEST
A
AA
AAL
AAPL
ABT
ZNGA
ZNGA
      Bin_1
      Bin_2
      px.xisx.1
      px.xisx.2
      Bin_0
      Bin_99
      Bin_56
              AAPL
              ADY
              AEIS
              AFAM
              AGP
              ALNY
              ZINC
      Bin_0
      Bin_1
            px.xbox.1
            px.xbox.2
     A
     B
     C
     D
     E
     F
     G
     H
     I
     J
     K
     L
     M
     N
     O
     P
     Q
     R
          S
          T
          U
          V
           W
           X
           Y
           Z
```

Comment: Okay, so you want members.  Can you give the exact output or data structure that you're attempting to obtain?

Comment: the output that I post is ok - it just gets loaded into a hash - i do not really understand why the amount of space changes for the different members. if it comes out all in one line with a newspace after each element that is fine. The flags on and off are so ugly.

Comment: Isn't this the sort of thing [`Text::Balanced`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ABalanced) is designed for?

Comment: Is this your config file for your application that you have full control over, or are you trying to read in something that already exists and is being used for other things? If the former, have you considered using something like Config::General or YAML instead?

Comment: the config file is static - I cannot change it. a few process read it in, and take different things from it. I can't change the format of the config file - the script extracts the member from the file - and compares it to another file

Comment: You realise that you can download a module and install it locally? It's usually just more Perl code files. Also, is the config file fixed-format or, for instance, can the opening brace be on the line following `label = `?

Comment: +1 - Question on SO rarely have as much detail. Thanks.

Comment: Or perhaps I spoke too soon. The Perl you show doesn't compile, and when it's fixed it doesn't produce that output from the given input.

Comment: It is a fixed format - so any gaps in the config file are mine - the bracket of the file are on the next line. there are not empty line in the config file and each line has a bracket or a text - if there is a empty line the process will actually ckoke. I have had it were I putin a new ine by mistake in the config file and the process quits

Comment: hm.. you have 45 `{` and only 43 `}`. somewhere missing 2x `}` check: `grep -oc '\{' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written just strips the comments and field names from the original file. There is no need to go to such lengths to do that.

This program produces the same output

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'penny_config.cfg';

while (<$fh>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  print unless /[#{}=]/;
}
```

Comment: I apologise. My original post was *"between edits"*. This one works fine

Answer (score 0):

Someone already comment that you should look at Config::General or YAML. You should look at Config::General and YAML.

YAML is JSON compatible, but offers more features than JSON. Since your data already looks a little bit like JSON, converting it to JSON would allow you to use existing JSON or YAML tools for interpreting it.

Config::General is modelled after the Apache Configuration File Format and has a better feature set than YAML. Once you become familiar enough with Config::General it would be just as easy to migrate your data to it as JSON. For one of my projects I wrote a configuration DSL in on top of Config::General. Config::General supports Comments, HereDocs, and multiple values for an item.

YAML and JSON are widely implemented in languages other than Perl. Config::General is Perl only.

If you can get modules installed I recommend that regardless of which you decide to use that you request installation of Config::General, YAML::XS, JSON, and or whichever alternate JSON modules you like. If that is a problem there are a number of solutions for installing Perl Modules either in your home directory or in your application.